# Creating an alphabet tracing app using flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, trace, letter

I'm trying to create an app that allows kids to practice writing letters by tracing them.

I created the letters using CustomPaint but I'm not sure how to restrict the user to only draw inside the letter and give them a feedback when they draw outside it or in a wrong way.

How can I know the points of the letter so that I only let them trace inside? Do you suggest other approaches to create an alphabet tracing app using flutter?

Comment: Hi! Did you find a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Draw a path for your alphabet and Use clip path in custom painter

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).